# Is there any function $f(z)$ such that $f(z)^i = z$?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

Basically, is there a formula for $\sqrt[i]{z}$.

I was thinking about complex numbers and trying to come up with formulas like $log_i(x)$ and $x^i$. I then thought about this:

$$\sqrt[i]{z} = f(z)$$

So I started trying. We know that $x^i = \cos(\ln(x))+i\sin(\ln(x))$, from Euler's formula. I then tried to reverse it:

$$\ln(x) \to e^x$$
$$\cos(x) \to \arccos(x)$$
$$...e^{\arccos(x)}$$

But, obviously, it will give you the wrong answer for $i\sin(\ln x)$.

I'm also unsure if $\arccos$ is even defined for values > 1.

Comment: $\arccos$ has a complex definition btw.  Mainly, look up hyperbolic trig functions.

Comment: @Olly Britton do the provided answers answer your question? If so, you should consider accepting one of them by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[i]{z}=z^{1/i}=z^{-i}$$

And then apply Euler's formula.

Comment: So it's
$$\cos(-\ln x) + i\sin(-\ln x)$$

Comment: @OllyBritton and take the negatives out of the trig functions for simplicity.

Comment: Wait... you can do that?

Comment: @OllyBritton $$\cos(-x)=\cos(x)\\\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

It's a multi-valued function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) for an explanation of branch cuts). Specifying a branch and taking an appropriate subset of $\mathbb{C}$ let's you define it on that subset.

To see how to define it, notice that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ and so $z^{\frac{1}{i}}=z^{-i}=\frac{1}{z^i}$ and see if you can derive it from there via Euler's formula.

Comment: Writing it as $z^{-i}$ is probably better for use though, but +1 anyways for covering everything.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1/i=-i$. So, we may in fact define 
$$
f(z)= z^{-i}
$$
Keep in mind, however, that $z^w$ is a multi-valued function for any non-real complex number $w$.